# Talend Open Studio JAR Properties

Tags: java, jar, talend, executable-jar

I need to export a JAR file from my Talend Open Studio project. In this project, I have inserted my connection properties to connect to MariaDB. This JAR file has to be executed by other people with different credentials in their database. Could they insert their properties dynamically to connect to their environment and execute my project? Also, which is more preferable, to export it as a JAR or executable JAR.

Answer (score 1):

To whom may be interested, I found a solution for my question. In order to achieve this, you have to **build** your job (as a standalone job) and then unzip the compressed file that comes out. In that file you will find everything you need so as to **run the project using the terminal and enter the content parameters** (if any).